# Symfony http cache manage dynamic expires time or how to invalidate cache?

Tags: symfony, http-caching

I not understand how to invalidate cache, because my appliaction not called when I return request with Expires header in first time and then application not called when try to call same request again

```
    $response
        ->setExpires($this->helper->getExpiresHttpCache());
```

And I added class

```
class CacheKernel extends HttpCache
{
protected function invalidate(Request $request, $catch = false)
{
    if ('PURGE' !== $request->getMethod()) {
        return parent::invalidate($request, $catch);
    }

    if ('127.0.0.1' !== $request->getClientIp()) {
        return new Response(
            'Invalid HTTP method',
            Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        );
    }

    $response = new Response();
    if ($this->getStore()->purge($request->getUri())) {
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK, 'Purged');
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, 'Not found');
    }

    return $response;
}

protected function getOptions()
{
    return [
        'default_ttl' => 0,
    ];
}
}
```

and in index.php add

```
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
// Wrap the default Kernel with the CacheKernel one in 'prod' environment
if ('prod' === $kernel->getEnvironment()) {
     $kernel = new CacheKernel($kernel);
}
```

but http cache works for each envirometns. Only when in browser disable checkbox `Disable cache` application will calling.

In browser I had correct header `Expires: Fri, 01 May 2020 11:59:00 GMT`. And if sent request again, with enable debug, debug not entered in application, but response contain result data. In this case `General` section contain `Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)`

```
Request URL: http://symfony.localhost/api/products/extra_fields
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

But wehere this point where compare current time and exprires time ? Example I want use global variables for expires time. Example after call some another api request `api/product/{id}` I want to change expires time for `/api/products/extra_fields`, but aplication not called, where I can manage it or it possible ? Could someone help me figure out how to manage it ?

```
Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.14
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 01 May 2020 07:39:35 GMT
Expires: Fri, 01 May 2020 11:59:00 GMT

Request
GET /api/products/extra_fields HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json
Referer: http://symfony.localhost/api/doc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
```